# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') whilte trying to accessing an array of object data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting **TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')** when I'm trying to access the data that I've pulled from my database (receivedData which is an object). I've tried `console.log` my `receivedData` and it does have data in it. Here's how my `social` [structure looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlYhH.jpg) like where it is one of the keys of my `receivedData object`.

```js
const logoObj = {
    "telegram": telegramWIcon,
    "twitter": twitterWIcon,
    "website": linkWIcon,
    "whitepaper": fileWIcon
  }

{receivedData.social[0] !== null &&
   <div>
       { Object.entries(receivedData.social[0]).forEach((item) =>
           item[1] !== null ? <SocialMedia url={logoObj.item[0]} link={item[1]} /> : ""
       )}
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error you get is not because `receivedData.social` is `undefined`? Try to add `receivedData.social && receivedData.social[0] !== null ...`

Comment: @Alexandr  Yup, here's the [error](https://imgur.com/a/nk5hSla)

Comment: Oh! I see: you try to get the field `item` of object `logoObj `, but I don't see the one in the object. Do you mean `logoObj[item[0]]`?

The rest code is raising questions too. At first, it looks like a good idea to replace `forEach` with `map`: the first returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const logoObj = {
  telegram: telegramWIcon,
  twitter: twitterWIcon,
  website: linkWIcon,
  whitepaper: fileWIcon,
};

{receivedData.social[0] !== null && (
  <div>
    {Object.entries(receivedData.social[0]).map(([type, link]) => {
      if (!link || !logoObj[type]) {
        returt null;
      }

      return <SocialMedia key={link} link={link} url={type} />;
    })}
  </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `item` field in `logoObj`. You need to access the key dynamically with `logoObj[item]`.

```js
const logoObj = {
    "telegram": telegramWIcon,
    "twitter": twitterWIcon,
    "website": linkWIcon,
    "whitepaper": fileWIcon
  }

{receivedData.social[0] !== null &&
   <div>
       { Object.entries(receivedData.social[0]).forEach((item) =>
           item[1] !== null ? <SocialMedia url={logoObj[item][0]} link={item[1]} /> : ""
       )}
   </div>
}
```